# What is the proper way to display a loading indicator while getting data from a URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I'm somewhat new to objective-c, i'm developing a news iOS application, the app gets all its contents using JSON parsing from a url, i'm using `AFNetworking` for that and this is the method that i made:

```
- (void)getContents
{
    NSString *urlString = @"http://some-url-that-has-json-output/";
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:self.articleId];
    NSLog(@"The call url is: %@",urlString);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //AFNetworking asynchronous url request
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                         initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"The JSON data is: %@", responseObject);
        jsonContents = [responseObject objectForKey:@"article"];
        [self LoadStructure];
    } failure:nil];
    [operation start];
}
```

Now the data loads fine with this method.

**My Question:** How to display a loading indicator (could be a GIF) while getting the data ? and is this method above is the proper or best way to get data from a url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use default loading indicator of iOS(UIActivityIndicator). You should start animating it before completion block and should hide inside success and failure block.

You should create a method using indicator as class variable:

```
indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
indicator.frame = CGRectMake(35, 15, 30, 30);
[self.view addSubview:indicator];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//AFNetworking asynchronous url request
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                     initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[indicator startAnimating];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"The JSON data is: %@", responseObject);
```

// to stop:

```
[indicator stopAnimating];
    jsonContents = [responseObject objectForKey:@"article"];
    [self LoadStructure];
} failure::^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    [indicator stopAnimating];
}];
[operation start];
```

Comment: i did, it's not showing, i also added this line `[indicator startAnimating]` after `[self.view addSubview:indicator]`

Comment: i'm using a scrollview, does that matter ?

Comment: please check with changing the frame of indicator

Comment: Check with adding indicator on ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window instead of self.view

Comment: i made it! thanks, i added it manually in the storyboard , it's working now, but i have to hide it after i stop the animation right ?

Comment: when you call [indicator stopAnimating]; it will automatically hide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78083/discussion-between-ana-and-ritu).

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop `UIActivityIndicatorView` into your XIB view and connect it with IBOutlet.

.h file

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView * activityIndicator;
```

Add UIActivity indicator view into your view. show it before

`NSString *urlString = @"http://some-url-that-has-json-output/";`

using:`[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];`

and stop it inside completion block and failure block

using: `[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];`

Comment: can you please post the whole updated method? where is the completion block?

Comment: `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess`..this is your completion block. Stop indicator before `NSLog(@"The JSON data is: %@", responseObject);`

Comment: so `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess` is a separate method and i have to call it inside my method above (before the nslog) ?

Comment: This `[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {` code will run when you receive data successfully from server. It is default block provided by AFNetworking.

Comment: ah ok sorry, let me test it :)

Comment: okay it's working now, but i have to hide it after i stop the animation right ?